# Google app engine terrible latency with specific pubsub messages

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm working on a project in the Google Cloud App Engine (node.js flexible runtime) and while I've had a pretty good experience with it thus far, I've recently ran into a problem where the engine will sometimes not respond a specific pubsub notification. Sometimes, the results will appear after a few minutes, but often times it requires me to redeploy the app and lose any messages that I had queued up prior. Interestingly enough, when I send a pubsub message through a different subscription, the engine responds to it well. The backlogged messages are then handled, but sending the problematic message again will still not work.

I'm not really sure how to solve this issue. There is no evidence that google received the message from pubsub in the logs. Additionally, waiting for this long will have negative impacts on the project overall, implying that the messages will reach the end destination given enough time.

I'm willing to provide more information to help reproduce the error.

Thanks in advance

**Edit**  The issue has increased significantly in severity. Please see the [updated post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51736428/pubsub-latency-reaching-minutes) I made to see the current extent of the issue.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "lose any messages that I had queued up prior". Please elaborate. If I understood you correctly then just don't [acknowledge](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/acknowledge) the message until it is completely processed.

Comment: You could print the message to the logs as soon as you receive it. Just print your output as you would normally do into [stdout](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging#appengine-vms).

Comment: When I redeploy the project, the messages that I had intended to go to app engine do not go to it. Ie if I were expecting 3 messages, got hit with latency and then redeployed, I wouldn't get a message when I looked into the logs after deploying. This is weird because the acknowledge call is a couple of lines below my print statement. Additionally, I do have statements to print the message to logs immediately after receiving it, but this message does not display when there is heavy latency.

Comment: I would suggest putting a more log output then and share snippets of your code that get stack, other wise it hard to understand what is happening.